# Two ruby versions, need tidying up

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sudo

I seem to have multiple ruby / rubygem installations on my server.

The gem environment for each is:

```
root@weepingangel:~# gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.2.0
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.1.0 (2013-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /root/.gem/specs
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
     - /root/.gem/ruby/2.1.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - :sources => ["http://gems.rubyforge.org", "http://gems.github.com"]
     - "gem" => "--no-ri --no-rdoc"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://gems.rubyforge.org
     - http://gems.github.com
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/bin
     - /usr/local/rbenv/libexec
     - /usr/local/rbenv/shims
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
```

---

```
root@weepingangel:~# sudo gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.11
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2011-10-30 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /var/lib/gems/1.9.1
     - /root/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - :sources => ["http://gems.rubyforge.org", "http://gems.github.com"]
     - "gem" => "--no-ri --no-rdoc"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://gems.rubyforge.org
     - http://gems.github.com
```

Does anyone know how I can clear these up as I only need one and I think I have things looking at my $PATH but it's pointing to the wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

If you use rbenv you can run this in your profile to set the default ruby environment.

```
$rbenv global 2.2.0
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer

Comment: That's subjective. It may be more useful than patchwork answer, and it is the right answer if you are a ruby practitioner.

Comment: Have you considered that this does not in any way provide a solution to the problem faced by the OP

Comment: I have this sorted out now. I saw the original comment about me learning to use rbenv correctly etc. I have been using rbenv for quite a while on my local system but I am setting up my first server for deploying my app onto and it is that where I had issues. The issues came from the fact that `gem install bundler` was not have the bash initialization done before the command was run due to Ansible. I have solved this now and it all works wonderfully!  Thanks!  BTW, I had already put in an `rbenv global` state in my ansible script when I originally installed rbenv.